Geopandas read_file is confusing me when used with 'sql' parameter
I have a demo function, this is a barebones function which can help with go through very big datasets and process the data without having to load that entire dataset into memory at a time

def generator(gpkg_file, chunk_size, offset, layer_name):
    while True:
        query = f"""
        SELECT *
        FROM {layer_name}
        LIMIT {chunk_size} OFFSET {offset}
        """
        gdf = gpd.read_file(gpkg_file, sql=query)
        if gdf.empty:
            break
        yield gdf
        offset += chunk_size

When I use this function in a jupyter notebook environment I get the expected result which is a dataframe with proper limits and offset and paginated data, But when I use the same in a flat python file it loads the entire gpkg file without the pagination, I am stumped and in desperate need for help
Click here to find the image
This is when used in a jupyter notebook environment, which is what I need.
But when used exactly like this in a python file it just loads the entire 175 rows (present in the demo.gpkg file) every iteration and since the df does not hit an end clause it goes on forever

Same environment too? The only difference is that the exact same code is in a .py file c.f. an .ipynb file?

Yup exact same environment, the only difference is one is a .py file (not working properly) and the other is a .ipynb file (working properly)

I can't reproduce. Could you try adding parameter engine=pyogrio to your read_filecommand? + add the output of geopandas.show_versions() + a listing of the packages in your environment to your question?

setting engine to pyogrio worked, thanks a lot, can you please explain this, I need to understand why it worked, can you please answer to this post and explain why this happened please? @Pieter

Using the sql parameter with geopandas.read_file is only supported when using the pyogrio read/write engine. If the fiona engine is used, the parameter will be simply ignored, and you'll get the effect you describe with the .py file.
As a workaround, you can force to use the pyogrio engine by adding an extra parameter engine="pyogrio", like this:
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpkg_file, sql=query, engine="pyogrio")

For the why... that might be somewhat complicated. In geopandas 0.x, fiona was the default engine, and there were some ways to activate pyogrio: e.g. via the above parameter or globally via an environment variable and it also depended on which engines were installed. In the recently released geopandas 1.x series, pyogrio has become the default. I suppose there is a combination of factors that leads to the different engine being used.
Personally, I would just make sure you are using geopandas 1.x and uninstall fiona: that should avoid the problem.

import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
def generator(gpkg_file, chunk_size, offset, layer_name):
engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{gpkg_file}')
while True:
query = f"""
SELECT * FROM {layer_name} LIMIT {chunk_size} OFFSET {offset}
"""
gdf = gpd.read_postgis(query, engine)
if gdf.empty:
break
yield gdf
offset += chunk_size

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
